# Site Contents is blank in Modern view of SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint

Site Contents is Blank in modern View, the Contents are showing blank but the subsites are visible, I have Installed all the latest patch update along with the language Pack but still is not working.

***/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx?view=14*** -- Not Showing the List of available Site Contents.

Browser Log shows /_api/web/AppTiles Status: 404 Not Found

[image]

Comment: There is no issue with the recent SharePoint 2019 Updates, Looks like it has broken as some of the files are not found, did you able to do **Site Provisioning** to see if that helps.